# V-cut gerber format

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, gerber

I prepared a panel on Eagle Cad. now I am preparing Gerber files for the production. What device output and file extension do I need to save the v-cut layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturer replied fast. So I keep the question and answer in case someone else needs it.

Gerber_RS274x standard and asked me to name .gbr extension (probably it is not a standard extension for v-cut work).